# updating the correct list data in listview when an event occurs

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, listener, listviewitem

I have a ListView which shows a list of objects for example CustomObject.

The list view is displayed fine.

I have a Callback listener in each custom Object, to update a boolean member in the CustomOject.

```
public class ListCustomObject extends Activity {
private CustomListAdapter adapter;
private ListView customList;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  adapter = new CustomListAdapter (this);
  customList= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.custom_list);
  List<CustomObject> customObjectList= getCustomObjects();
  adapter.addObjects(customObjectList);
  customList.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class CustomObject implements MonitoringListner{
     String name;
     boolean entered;

     @Override
     public void onEnteredRegion() {
        entered=true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onExitedRegion() {
        entered=false;
    }
}
```

i am displaying both 'Name' and 'entered' in the listItem.

The problem is, when the callback arrives and changes the boolean value to true. Its not reflecting in the listview.

How to update the corresponding list item when callback event arrives for corresponding object?.

Please help.

Awaiting for some answers.

Comment: when did you used the CustomObject. also post it where you used it

Comment: You have to call notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter of the listview after you have made changes to custom object(s). This will tell the listview to update its data and then the new info will be displayed.

Comment: Call/Initialize this line adapter = new CustomListAdapter (this); after List<CustomObject> customObjectList= getCustomObjects(); this line.

Answer (score 1):

use this code to notify listview

```
public class ListCustomObject extends Activity {
private CustomListAdapter adapter;
private ListView customList;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter (this);
    customList= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.custom_list);
    List<CustomObject> customObjectList= getCustomObjects();
    adapter.addObjects(customBeaconList);
    customList.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class CustomObject implements MonitoringListner{
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;
    public CustomObject(CustomListAdapter adapter) {
        this.adapter = adapter;
    }
    String name;
    boolean entered;

    @Override
    public void onEnteredRegion() {
        entered=true;
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onExitedRegion() {
        entered=false;
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

and when you want create CustomObject pass adapter to constructor.